# Akka StateMachine Replication for Redundancy

Tags: akka

I have a Microservice application in which I have a set of actors with each actor acting as a digital twin for say a Power producing unit. This actor gets messages from the PowerPlant and for each message I get, I evolve the state of my Actor.

There is another upstream Microservice that actually reads the state of the state machine for each actor. So far so good!

I now want to have redundancy built in. This means that I want multiple instances of my Microservice that contains the StateMachine to be run. The problem now is how will the upstream systems see a consistent state for a single PowerPlant? The upstream systems gets state messages from the time they ask to the Microservice via a HTTP endpoint the current state of the PowerPlant.

I see that there are several possibilities with which I could replicate the Akka actor that contains the StateMachine, but I'm not sure if any of those solutions might work! One such approach is here 
https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5.5/scala/distributed-data.html

Any other suggestions?

EDIT: I have a full running application here - https://github.com/joesan/plant-simulator/ This application contains the StateMachine that I was talking about! It you navigate to the https://github.com/joesan/plant-simulator/tree/master/app/com/inland24/plantsim/services/simulator/onOffType and you will find there an Actor and the corresponding StateMachine. The StateMachine is evolved by the messages the Actor receives!

Comment: Your link doesn't work

Comment: I just fixed it! Sorry about that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One classic solution is to use Akka Cluster Sharding coupled with Akka Persistence.

Sharding means that each PowerPlant exists only once in your cluster (no data sync issues), but that if the server it resides on goes down (exits the cluster), the actor is re-created somewhere else. Akka Persistence then makes sure your restore the actor state when it’s recreated.

Documentation:
https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/cluster-sharding.html
https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/persistence.html